# Google script won't setValue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to change the value of a cell in a loop. All variables are defined as they should be but the status itself won't change and returns an `undefined` or `Function not found` error.

My code is the following

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  
var numRows = 3;  

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8)

var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    var name = row[0];  
    var name2 = row[1]; 
    var mother = row[2]; 
    var father = row[3]; 
    var sister = row[4]; 
    var grandpa = row[5]; 
    var mail = row[6];
    var type = row[7];
    var status = row[8];
    var done = "DONE";
    var not_done = "NOT DONE";


    if (status = "TODO") {
      //Do something...
      status.setValue(done);
    }

     else {
    //Do nothing...
    }
}
```

Heading of the sheet are these:

```
Name    Name2   Mother  Father  Sister  Grandpa  Mail   Type    Status
```

I tried adding a new loop

```
for (var i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    sheet.getRange(i+2, 9).setValue("DONE");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

but this resulted in changing contents of other rows to and also an extra loop which shouldn't be necessary.
What (small) thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are defining the `numColumns` to have 8 columns in total while the status field is 9th column (you started counting at 0). Hence it lies outside the range that you defined. In the 2nd one, it sorta worked because your range is 9.

Comment: My bad, but still doesn't fix the issue. Getting `Function not found`

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is that `status` is a value not a cell object thus it has no "setValue".  You should use the debugger which would have told you the exact line and problem. In the 2nd case you are using getRange correctly.
also as another answer says you are using different column indexes (8 and 9 respectively)

Comment: How should I declare status as a cell object so I can use setValue with it? I tried using the `row` variable but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You need to build a range object. You already do on to which is also what the other answer shows

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to replicate what you were trying to do is replace:

```
for (i in data) {
```

with:

```
for (var i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
```

and replace:

```
status.setValue(done);
```

with:

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(done);
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried that, this adds "Done" to rows I20-I21 and I22 instead of 2, 3 and 4. I've updated my question to show what I'm trying to do with the loop.